# How can I download a previous git commit in Netbeans?

Tags: git, netbeans

I see Revert Commit. Will that erase current commits? I just want to pull a previous commit without affecting the overall project. Thanks.

Comment: You want `git checkout`.

Comment: You want your local code to become the same as the repository code?

Comment: Lefteris Bab, Yes, the same as a commit from yesterday, but not the most recent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the answer for you

Scenario:

1)User selects a versioned context and invokes 'revert' from the main menu

2)Dialog pops up asking for additional revert options - revisions etc.

3)A new revision is created which reverts the previous commits

***Command Line***

1) You have to see all commits. Use `git log`. You will see the commits with hascode, then

2)Then use `git reset --hard <SHAsum of your commit>`

See [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

Comment: In my opinion in this case the best is to use command line and this is because you use Netbeans. With eclipse things are much easier.

Comment: Thanks. Will doing this erase the most recent commit? I don't want to erase others work or force others to use a previous commit.

Comment: @bstrong See the modified answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to re-clone the project to see if this resolves the issue I'm having, but it it doesn't I'll try that.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project and then Git->Checkout->Checkout Revision...
You won't loose your commits, you only set the head to a specific commit/revision.

Comment: For everyone wondering how he gets the latest version back then, use Git->Checkout->Checkout Revision..., hit Select and choose the master branch and check it out.